# Rewrite not working with certain words in the url but works with others

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

Ok so I have a rule setup:

```
RewriteRule ^park/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+) /park.php?id=$1
```

I go to the url https://test/park/123 and nothing gets picked up on the page which contains the following code:

```
echo $_GET["id"];
```

If I change the rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^hello/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+) /park.php?id=$1
```

Then use the url https://test/hello/123 it works and the page displays 123. I have just moved from PC to Mac. It works on the hosting server but not locally. It just seems very bizarre, am I missing anything?

Comment: Did it work on Windows and now it does not on Mac?  Same Apache version between both?  Is PHP configured on your Mac so the `echo $_GET["id"];` is run?  You could get nothing either because of the rewrite, or because PHP just does not run.

Comment: On windows I had it on IIS using their rewrite tool. The web host I use on the internet is apache. I had a htaccess file for the server with the same rules as IIS all working correctly.

Everything is setup on the mac and is working correctly. The strange things is that it isn't working with the word park. If I change that to something else the id is echoed out onto the page. Not seen that before.

Comment: Are there any other rules that could apply to the word "park" and not the other words?  If that other rule has the `[L]` option, it would stop there and never reach the rule you want to add here.

Comment: I have taken all other rules out of the file to isolate it, that is why it seems so strange.

Comment: hum, check with the editor mode of a browser  what redirect you are receiving with "park" and some other word.  There has to be a difference in what you are receiving.

Comment: It's not a redirect, it's a rewrite.